# Git diff after push on AWS CodeCommit

Tags: git, aws-lambda, aws-codecommit

I'm new in AWS CodeCommit and I would like to get git diff on my email after every push on remote repository.

I have set up trigger to receive email upon push via SNS, but is there possibility to use lambda function to get pure git diff from last commit?

Answer (score 1):

If you configure your Lambda function to use CodeCommit as a trigger, you will get the commit id in your Lambda `event`.

Using the commit id, you can then use `aws-sdk`'s [`getCommit()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CodeCommit.html#getCommit-property) and/or even [`getDifferences()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CodeCommit.html#getDifferences-property) to retrieve the diff for that commit and send it to AWS SES.

Comment: But if you use getDifferences() you will not get JSON like response with some information that is not same as git diff??

Comment: @user821738 What do you mean? Can you post what you are currently getting with `getCommit()` and `getDifferences()`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Have CodeCommit trigger a Lambda function.
2. Package `git` with the Lambda function. The easiest way to do this may be with [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-git), although that will require you to write your function in NodeJS. If you wanted to use another language like Python you might download the git tar file from that NodeJS library and use it in your Python function.
3. Have your Lambda function extract the git commit ID from the message that triggered it.
4. Have your Lambda function execute a `git diff` to obtain the diff for that commit.
5. Have your Lambda function email the diff via AWS SES.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do implement lambda function with Node.js

Answer (score 0):

So I have not tested this workflow, but I suspect you could get it to work for your use case.

Steps:

1. Configure a CodeCommit trigger for your repository to notify a Lambda function. This payload will include the new commit id of the tip of the branch each time you make a push.
2. In your lambda function, use CodeCommit's [GetCommit](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/APIReference/API_GetCommit.html) API to get the list of parent commit Ids you wish to diff against. Unless the commit is a merge, there should be only 1 parent.
3. For each parent commit, use CodeCommit's [GetDifferences](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/APIReference/API_GetDifferences.html) API to get a list of each file which was Added, Modified, or Deleted.
4. For each set of files which was changed, use CodeCommit's [GetBlob](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/APIReference/API_GetBlob.html) API to return the contents of the files as Base64-encoded strings. Pass these strings to a diff library to render the diff as HTML. I suspect something like [viranch/Diffy](https://github.com/viranch/diffy) could work (although I haven't tried myself).
5. Once you have the HTML diff payloads, send them off to SNS or SES for emailing.